# Xtext formatting2 API - Interior indentation of an EList<EObject> feature

Tags: eclipse, formatting, xtext

I am following up on [Indent lines of text using Xtext formatting API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61699940/indent-lines-of-text-estring-using-xtext-formatting-api) to ask a slightly different question, now that I know more about what I'm talking about.

I am having trouble using the formatting2 API to indent elements which get assigned to a list.

Here is a full example that demonstrates the problem:

*MyDsl.xtext*

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl hidden(WS)

import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore
generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Model:
    greeting=Greeting
;

Greeting:
    'Hello' ','? name=SIMPLE_WORD '!' NL+
    lines+=Line*
;

Line: {Line}
    SIMPLE_WORD+
    NL
;

terminal SIMPLE_WORD: 
    ('0'..'9' | 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') 
    ('0'..'9' | 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '-' | '_')*
;
terminal NL: ('\r'? '\n');
terminal WS: (' ' | '\t');
```

*MyDslFormatter.xtend*

```java
class MyDslFormatter extends AbstractFormatter2 {

    @Inject extension MyDslGrammarAccess

    def dispatch void format(Model model, extension IFormattableDocument document) {
        model.greeting.format()

        println(document)
    }

    def dispatch void format(Greeting greeting, extension IFormattableDocument document) {
        for (line : greeting.lines) {
            line.format()
            line.prepend[indent]
        }
    }

    def dispatch void format(Line line, extension IFormattableDocument document) {
        // TODO...
    }
}
```

*MyDslFormattingTest.xtend*

```java
@RunWith(XtextRunner)
@InjectWith(MyDslInjectorProvider)
class MyDslFormattingTest {

    @Inject extension FormatterTestHelper

    @Test
    def void indentLines() {
        assertFormatted[
            toBeFormatted = '''
                Hello, World!
                The quick brown fox
                Jumps over the lazy dog
            '''
            expectation = '''
                Hello, World!
                    The quick brown fox
                    Jumps over the lazy dog
            '''
        ]
    }
}
```

Output:

```
----------- RootDocument with ITextReplacers (syntax: <offset|text>) -----------
Hello, World!
<14|>The quick brown fox
<34|>Jumps over the lazy dog
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14 0 "": HiddenRegionReplacer: indentInc=1;indentDec=1
34 0 "": HiddenRegionReplacer: indentInc=1;indentDec=1
```

Test fails due to no indentation.

I have tried many ways to go about this, but every time I think I have something that will work, it will always lead to the `indentInc=1;indentDec=1` result, causing indentation to cancel out.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, or how to go about solving this?

Cheers and thank you!

Comment: Well this is strange... searches for "indentInc=1;indentDec=1" only yield this post, so clearly I'm doing something wrong here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the test to pass with

```java
def dispatch void format(Greeting greeting, extension IFormattableDocument document)  {
    val begin = greeting.regionFor.ruleCallTo(NLRule)
    val end = greeting.lines.last.regionFor.ruleCallTo(NLRule)

    interior(begin, end)[indent]
    for (line : greeting.lines) {
        line.format
        line.prepend[indent]
    }
}
```

[Answer](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1103866&goto=1827739&#msg_1827739) courtesy of [Tamás](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=usrinfo&id=210532&) on the Xtext community forum.